(raylib) exit code: -1073741819 (0xc0000005)
I'm using visual studio and I made this program with raylib to draw text (using a different font) in a window.
And then this happened:
myprogram.exe (process 28468) exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005)
This is the source code:
#include <raylib.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    const int screenWidth = 1080;
    const int screenHeight = 768;
    
    Font font = LoadFont("assets/font.ttf");
    InitWindow(screenWidth, screenHeight, "test");

    SetTargetFPS(60);

    Vector2 vector{ 20.00f, 30.00f };
    while (!WindowShouldClose()) {
    
        BeginDrawing();

            ClearBackground(WHITE);
            DrawTextEx(font, "Hello World!", vector, 20.0, 10, BLACK);

        EndDrawing();
    
    }

    UnloadFont(font);
    CloseWindow();

    return 0;
}

I used a debugger and it made me go to rlgl.h and show me where the error was
if ((!RLGL.ExtSupported.texCompDXT) && ((format == RL_PIXELFORMAT_COMPRESSED_DXT1_RGB) || (format == RL_PIXELFORMAT_COMPRESSED_DXT1_RGBA) || (line 2984)

The thing you should look for is not where the error occured (that's rarely helpful) but where in your code called the place where the error occured. You can find that out by looking at the stack trace that the debugger shows you. Each function calls another function which calls another function and so on. This is called the stack trace. Look up the stack trace until you find the place in your main function that caused the error.

My guess would be LoadFont is failing which then causes a crash when the code attempts to use the font
